# Using a "Normal" powerbank for a "Super Fast Charging" phone, are there any potential damages?

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, charger, smartphones, mobile-phones

I have an Anker Redux 10000 mAh powerbank and a Samsung Note 10 Lite smartphone.

My powerbank is capable of providing an output of 5V ⎓ 2.4A, with only "normal" charging mode (no QuickCharge or other similar charging technologies). That would make its maximum power to be 5V x 2.4A = 12W.

My phone is equipped with Samsung's 25W "Super Fast Charging" capability. According to the information printed on the charger provided with the phone, this is the output specification (which is the one confusing me):

> (PDO) 5V ⎓ 3A or 9V ⎓ 2.77A (PPS) 3.3-5.9V ⎓ 3A or 3.3-11V ⎓ 2.25A

If I understand it correctly, my phone could be charged with a broad range of voltage-amperage values. According to the information printed on the charger, it can receive a wattage as low as 3.3V x 2.25A = 7.425W, which is well within the 12W capability of my powerbank.

So, if I use my powerbank to charge my phone, will I damage my phone or my powerbank or both? Also, am I understanding electricity correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Surely the phone tries to negotiate what kind of power supply there is, and then it will draw only standard amount of current if there is no fancy high current charger present.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a Samsung A6 and I use all manner of chargers that are available to me at the time with no ill effects whatsoever so far.